# if $Y\sim \textrm{Bin}(n,\alpha) \space,\space X\mid Y\sim \textrm{Bin}(Y,\beta)$ then $X\sim \textrm{Bin}(n,\alpha \beta)$

Tags: probability, summation

Suppose \begin{equation*}Y\sim\textrm{Bin}(n,\alpha)\space,\space (X\mid Y)\sim\textrm{Bin}(Y,\beta)\end{equation*}I'm trying to prove that $X\sim\textrm{Bin}(n,\alpha \beta)$.
I began with saying that \begin{equation*}P_X(x)=\sum _y P_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)P_Y(y)\end{equation*}and got to the equation:\begin{equation*}P_X(x)={n \choose x}\left(\alpha\beta\right)^{x}\sum_{k=0}^{n-x}{n-x \choose k}\left(1-\beta\right)^{k}\alpha^{k}\left(1-a\right)^{n-x-k}\end{equation*}I tried taking $(1-\alpha \beta)^x$ out of the sum while keeping the sum equal to 1 (this would have finished the proof) but anything I tried has failed and at this point I'm not sure that this is the right way to treat the question.
What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are literally almost there:  you just have to apply the binomial theorem $$(s+t)^r = \sum_{u=0}^r \binom{r}{u} s^u t^{r-u},$$ with the choice $s = (1-\beta)\alpha$, $t = 1-\alpha$, $r = n-x$, $u = k$, to obtain $$\Pr[X = x] = \binom{n}{x} (\alpha \beta)^x \left( (1-\beta)\alpha + (1-\alpha) \right)^{n-x},$$ which simplifies to the desired probability mass function for $X$.